# How to start a server for a javascript library

Tags: javascript, server, local

This is a totally newbie question as I am trying t learn by experimenting.
I was trying to look through [Tracking.js](https://trackingjs.com/docs.html#introduction)

.I came through this point

> While you're working, you'll need a basic HTTP server to serve your pages. Test out the web server by loading the finished version of the project. For example: http://localhost:8000/tracking.js/

I don't understand , what am I required to do in this.
Also, on theoretical note , how are js applications deployed in local port.
I know we can set a local server through python by7 going to current directory.But I am clueless,for eg. I downloaded the tracking.js and I want to set up server without using python instead using javascript, then how should I implement that, If I want to do it without installing another package.
For eg. sometimes we can use server.js and sometime in app.js we make a port to listen.

Any clearance on this is appreciated ,thanks.

Comment: Welcome. As this isn't quite a programming question, it is considered off-topic. In any case, you might benefit from reading about [Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model) and [Client-server model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model). And of course, have a read at Stack Overflow's [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), if you haven't already.

Comment: JavaScripts eco-system has cultivated to include server side javascript development. Whether that's a good thing or not is up for debate but you should take a look at Node.js https://nodejs.org/en/

Comment: @Marc.2377 This is actually on-topic, as it deals with tools that programmers use. That said, it's probably too broad to answer adequately in a Q&A forum. A tutorial or even a book will probably be more useful. If the current tutorial is too confusing, I recommend finding another one.

Comment: @JDB Ah, you're right indeed. And I second these suggestions - reading a book or textbook, specially.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this, is by using `npm` module `lite-server`.

```
$ npm i -g lite-server
```

After that is finished installing, navigate to your project folder where `index.html` is located, open up a terminal within that folder and type

```
$ lite-server
```

(If you are using `Windows`, you can navigate to your project folder, hold `Shift` and press `Right Click` and you should see an option `Open up PowerShell window here`)

This will automatically create a local server for you and open up your default browser. It also has automatic reload, so when you make a change to any of the documents, the browser will reload automatically.

And keep the `terminal` or `PowerShell` window open as long as you are working with the project.

Comment: If they aren't sure how to start a web server I would question what their knowledge of the command line and NPM are and whether this information is useful at all.

Comment: He can search on Google what `npm` is.

Comment: He can search google how to install and start a web server, too. That doesnt really get him any closer than he already is

Comment: Hah, I guess you're right, haven't thought about that.